# XSS in <a> tag in document.write

Tags: webforms, xss, string-interpolation

I have an application made with ASP.NET WebForms. It has breadcrumbs section, which is getting flagged for potential cross-site scripting vulnerabilities by Veracode. I have narrowed down the exact part that it's happening. There is a document.write that creates an `<a>` tag link, and the variable within the tag ( `subs[i]` ) is what is flagged. I've checked, and any string variable interpolation causes the XSS flag there, even if I make one myself (I tried `var testString = "this is a test";`). If there is only text there, the flag goes away (ie: `<a>not a variable</a>`)

```
function breadCrumbs(base,delStr,defp,cStyle,tStyle,dStyle,nl) 
{ 
    loc=window.location.toString(); //current href
        defp = '#';
    subs=loc.substr(loc.indexOf(base)+base.length+1).split("/");
    document.write('<a href="'+getLoc(subs.length-1)+defp+'" class="'+cStyle+'">Home</a>  '+'<span class="'+dStyle+'">'+delStr+'</span> ');
    a=(loc.indexOf(defp)==-1)?1:2;
        a = 2;
    for (i=a+1;i<(subs.length - 1);i++) 
    { 
        subs[i]=formatDir(unescape(subs[i]));
//THE BELOW LINE IS WHERE IT OCCURS
        document.write('<a href="'+getLoc(subs.length-i-2)+defp+'" class="'+cStyle+'">'+subs[i]+'</a>  '+'<span class="'+dStyle+'">'+delStr+'</span> ');
    }
    if (nl==1) 
        document.write("<br>");
    document.write('<span class="'+tStyle+'">'+document.title+'</span>');
}
```

I have a function that I had hoped would work as a sort of XSS blocker, but it doesn't work.

```
function formatDir(tempStr)
{
    dir = trimBlanks(tempStr.replace(/[A-Z]/g, " $&"));
    dir = dir.replace(/[^-a-z0-9]/gi, '');
    return dir;
}
```

Does anyone know of something I can add to protect it?